# how to check if a model table is created or not

Tags: django

Im trying to create a tuple from another model's objects and use it in another model.
it works just fine but when when I want to start my app and makemigrations, it gives me the error that the model you are trying to use is not created yet, obviously! therefore, I need an if statement to check if that model table is not created dont do anything.
this is my Model:

```
class Field(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='default')
    title = CharField(max_length=32)
```

and my tuple:

```
INTERESTS = (Field.objects.values_list('slug', 'title'))
```

and this is the error I get:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: reg_field
```

how can I bypass this error?
I need something like this:
if Field exists then: INTERESTS = the above, else INTERESTS = ()

Comment: Your migrations are essentially a history of your model changes, so it seems to me you have done something a little odd when you've created the tables and set the choices in the first place. Then you've managed to get it running locally somehow, but the migrations themselves are still out of sequence.

Comment: if I comment INTERESTS and migrate then again remove the comment, everything works. But I want things to be automatic. how can I refer INTERESTS to Field after the Field migration is finished?

Comment: You need to look at what order you have done things in the migrations files ... as I say, these are in a specific order. If this is a brand new deployment, you _could_ potentially remove them all and recreate them as a single migration which might solve the problem. Don't do this if this is an ongoing project though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commenting this line:

```
# INTERESTS = (Field.objects.values_list('slug', 'title'))
```

Then running `makemigrations` and `migrate` and then trying again?
If you're trying to execute code that makes use of an unmigrated model it certainly won't work.

--- OR --

Move that row inside a method so it's not evaluated when executing `makemigrations`

```
def my_method():
    INTERESTS = (Field.objects.values_list('slug', 'title'))
```

Comment: the problem is I need to commit these files to the main repository and we dont commit db.sqlite3 or the migrations. so, how do I refer INTERESTS to Field model when they want to makemigrations for the first time?

Comment: Where is this line? Queries are lazily evaluated so why is django trying to execute it when you run `makemigrations` ? If you place it inside of a view or inside a method of some kind it'll probably be ok

Comment: could you please help me write the method?

Comment: where should I add this method? inside my field model?

Comment: Where was this row in the first place? What goal are you trying to achieve with it? Why are you trying to save that data into a constant? If you can explain me a little better what you're trying to do I can help you figure out what to do. Feel free to answer by updating your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238309/discussion-between-sam-and-beikeni).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is wrong.
It is wrong to try to create tables while running your code.

Instead, make sure your tables are set but empty.

You can check if the table is empty instead.

To check if a table is empty.. Use this

```
Objs = Mymodel.objects.all()
If objs is None:
    # your code goes here
```

Comment: still gives me the reg_field error.

Comment: Even when the table has been created?